# Doubt related to venturimeter and manometric fluid

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, measurements

I am unable to understand why the manometric fluid do not flush off due to high pressure fluid flowing through pipe? Because as discharge increases pressure drop will increase so manometer should show more reading, but there must be a maximum limit for that.
Also I am not able to understand that we connect one limb of manometer at inlet of converging section and other at throat but why we don't connect one limb at throat and other at end of diverging section, is there any problem if we connect it like that?

Answer (score 0):

So, for all the positions you mention, then the pressure difference should be considered which will define the length of the manometer limbs or the length of the slope depending which design you use.